# How to add year display script in $('body').append Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javas experts,

i have this script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  var credits= $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft"></div><div id="wrapright">Designed Templatezy</div></div></div>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Now i want to add year script  `<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>` to that `<div id="wrapleft">` div:

**see example below:**

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var credits= $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft"> document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</div><div id="wrapright">Designed Templatezy</div></div></div>');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

I add my year script as the above but it does not worked, i am not well expert in java or jquery, so please anyone can add this year script same to that id in append body. thanks and hope to see your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
$('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">'+year+'</div><div id="wrapright">Designed Templatezy</div></div></div>');
```

Also, note that javascript is not java, they are totally different!

Comment: you are awesome man, your code worked for me http://bolina-fashion.blogspot.com/...it show 2016 as the next year come, it will update to 2017 automatically ?...thanks again.

Comment: Of course, since the system has the correct date. This is what the documentation says `If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.`

Comment: Please, check as the correct answer if you think that it was :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding the piece of JavaScript code as text, to the first parameter of [JQuery's Append function](http://api.jquery.com/append/). That parameter should be a DOM element, an array of elements, a HTML string, or a jQuery object.

JQuery will interpret your parameter value as a HTML string, and therefor the JavaScript code won't be executed.

You should break the text, so the code will be executed before being send to JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var fullYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var credits= $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">' + fullYear + '</div><div id="wrapright">Designed Templatezy</div></div></div>');
});
```

Also note that you weren't closing the Ready function properly.

Comment: your code display the year but it reflect some other parts of my sites..so the code shared by david worked. thanks for your support.